# How to download Mongodb 3.0?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have used PHP Version 5.3, So i need to Download MongoDB 3.0 and PHP Driver version 1.6  how to download older version (3.0) of MongoDB and PHP Driver.. And also i want use PHP composer and already i have used Composer for like `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"` (for PHP Driver version 1.0), Now i want to use PHP composer for PHP Driver Version 1.6..

`composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.6.0"` is it Possible?

please suggest your solution and post download link for MongoDB3.0

Comment: Here is the mongo download locatio https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl?_ga=1.29864127.149489430.1481867183

Comment: .exe file not there in your suggest download path, only available installed folder... i have downloded folder as you suggested how to config that folder..@user1211

Comment: It seems the name of the question isn't correct

Comment: This link works in 2020: https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl

Answer (score 3):

You can download MongoDB from here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community

Just scroll down a bit and there's a link named "All Version Binaries" just below the download button. It opens a page that lists all previous releases of MongoDB. Also, remember to select your OS before clicking on the link.

Comment: Mentioning links can be done in the comments section. Answer section must contain **your** contribution

Comment: Not enough rep to comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To start mongo you need to unzip the folder and start with /mongod.exe (in windows).
My suggestion is to create an data folder and specify dbpath as the data folder. Their are various other parameters as well which you can configure. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) is the further installation details.

Once you start the server, verify you can connect to it. You can use a GUI tool (Robomongo works best) or you can use mongo shell command.

To access mongo via php, you can refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/#access-mongodb-from-php)

Please let us know if you face errors.

Comment: directly i have to tried run mongod.exe but doesnot work.. if i have set environmental variable for current folder path it may work?@user1211

Comment: finally i have unziped folder in D Drive, and my folder struture is `D:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin` and i have created data folder and db folder as `D:\MongoDB\Data\db` nxt what can i do? can i set Environment path? @user1211

Comment: To start mongo you need to run mongod.exe. For example, from the Command Prompt:  D:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath D:\MongoDB\Data\db

Comment: i have already used phpdriver version 1.0 and php composer for 1.0  ( mongo3.2 with php 5.5) can i use same driver and composer?@user1211

Comment: how to create batch file to start mongo `(D:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath D:\MongoDB\Data\db)` @user1211

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb  has all ur answers and to fetch latest mongodb releases. And as far as i know PHP Driver version 1.5 and 1.6 are only compatible for PHP version 5.3.

Ref : https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Answer (score 0):

did you try this link?

https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community

Allows you to select between various editions.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment of this writing the MongoDB Driver Library `mongodb/mobgodb` has version `1.1.1`.

How are you going to use version `1.6`?

It has also following requirements:

- php: >=5.4
- ext-mongodb: ^1.2.0

So, it does not work with PHP 5.3

Comment: which version of PHP driver i can use with Mongodb 3.0 with php 5.3? @Gennadiy Litvinyuk

Comment: can i use `1.1.0` version of PHP driver ? @Gennadiy Litvinyuk

Answer (score -2):

At the moment of this writing the MongoDB Driver Library mongodb/mobgodb has version 1.1.1.
There are many way to use in different versions.
How do you use version 1.6?

Some requirements are needed :

```
php: >=5.4
ext-mongodb: ^1.2.0
```

So, you do not use it with PHP 5.3

Comment: Did you just paraphrased my answer?